# Getting black screen in visual studio after Installation completed

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I was getting black screen after opening Visual studio each time. I got a solution from Stack overflow i.e code --disable-gpu. It is working fine but my main issue is when I use to code in vs code. I am not getting suggestions as intellisense is not working and I am unable to install any extensions from Visual studio code.

Comment: can u please specify which OS u are using ?

Comment: Windows 7 64 bit os

Comment: please find the link of screenshot :- https://imghostr.com/7bRcn8gP6

Comment: are you run it as administrator ?

Comment: As I have mentioned earlier, I am unable to open application directly. I can only open through the command - "code --disable-gpu".   I have uninstalled many times and installed it but still I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 3):

to disable hardware acceleration permanently (without adding --disable-gpu argument) open folder "C:\Users\your_username_here\.vscode" than open file argv.json with any editor and look for
**"//disable-hardware-acceleration": true,** and just remove the tow slashes before disable. i think there is a similar workaround in linux

Answer (score 1):

Hit Ctrl Shift P to open the command palette,
Type Developer and choose Developer: Toggle Developer Tools.
switch to the Network tab in Dev tools.
Search for extensions now

Comment: Shall I try to install any extension after that. Please reply quickly

Comment: please find the link of screenshot :- https://imghostr.com/7bRcn8gP6.  I am getting the same error as shown in the screenshot

Comment: try run the application as administrator then try install any extension let me know if it working fine

Comment: As I have mentioned earlier, I am unable to open application directly. I can only open through the command - "code --disable-gpu".   I have uninstalled many times and installed it but still I am facing the same issue

Comment: Can you please try run it as administrator from command line this will help you to do it https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/05cce5f6-3c3a-4bb8-8b72-8c1ce4b5eff1/how-to-run-a-program-as-adminitrator-via-the-command-line?forum=w7itproappcompat

Answer (score 0):

Go to properties of visual studio
change target . Add `--disable-gpu`
make sure to add a space before --
it will resolve your issue.

Comment: Please write well, nice and format your code blocks. Follow this link: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks